# How to group by counts in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a devices collection in MongoDB. This devices collection has a field shop that shows which device is belong to which shop.

I can get number of devices using in a shop by:

```
db.getCollection('devices').aggregate(
   [
      {
        $group : {
           _id : "$shop",
           count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      }
   ]
)
```

But I need some different data. I want to group shops  by number of devices. Result should be:

```
{
    "numberOfDevices": 0,
    "numberOfShops": 10
},
{
    "numberOfDevices": 1,
    "numberOfShops": 15
},
{
    "numberOfDevices": 2,
    "numberOfShops": 34
}...
```

and so on. What should I do for such a query?

Update:

I found a solution after Alex Blex comment:

```
db.getCollection('devices').aggregate(
   [
  {
    $group : {
       _id : "$shop",
       count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
      $group: {
            _id: "$count" ,
            shops: { $addToSet: { shop: "$_id"} } 
          }
  },
  { $sort : { "_id" : 1 } }
  ]
)
```

Thank you Alex

Comment: Another `$group` in the pipeline?

Comment: Maybe, but I really don't know how to do

Comment: Did you try?https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/ has handful of examples.